# HTTP запрос, с длиной ссылки примерно в 3тыс символов, выдает ошибку

Tags: php, url

Использую на PHP функцию `file_get_contents()`. Когда длина **url** строки не большая, то все работает. Но мне нужно делать запрос по API одного сайта, в котором парсятся элементы из строки **url** . И когда пытаюсь сделать запрос с длиной ссылки примерно в 3тыс символов, мне выдается ошибка

```
Warning: file_get_contents(''): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403
```

Не пойму в чем проблема, и как её решить.

Ссылку в `urlencode()` обернул, и если ввести её в браузере, то запрос обрабатывается нормально.
Может нужно что-то поменять в `ini_set()` или еще где?

Comment: Прочтите вот этот пост. Судя по всему, длинна URL больше 1000 символов может обрабатываться не корректно: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549993/maximum-uri-length-for-file-get-contents

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в следующем:

- в качестве метода отправки данных вы используете метод GET, используйте метод POST. С помощью GET лучше отправить небольшие тестовые данные. Максимальный объем здесь 4 Кб. Для POST такого явного ограничения нет.
- также в настройках самого сервере бывает, стоит ограничение на размер передаваемых файлов, нужно проверить этот параметр.
- сервер ожидает один метод передачи данных а вы используете другой